# Why doesn't the compiler optimize out increments when used only in a boolean inequality?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I am writing a simple for loop that checks if there is an even number and an odd number inside an array.

What I am trying to figure out is why incrementing a local variable to just use as a boolean is not optimized out and it is still incremented every loop.

I have limited the count to uint8_t whereas the counter is uint32_t such that there is no chance of overflow.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/H7l-Ht

Assembly output can be seen in the godbolt link but C code pasted here to be seen easily.

The first loop just setting the value to true and false;

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h> 

bool hasEvenAndOdd(int* values, uint8_t count) {

    uint32_t even = 0;
    uint32_t odd = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (values[i] % 2 == 1) {
            odd = 1;
        } else {
            even = 1;
        }
    }

    return (even && odd);
}
```

The second loop with the counter:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

bool hasEvenAndOdd(int* values, uint8_t count) {

    uint32_t even = 0;
    uint32_t odd = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (values[i] % 2 == 1) {
            odd++;
        } else {
            even++;
        }
    }

    return (even && odd);
}
```

I guess my question is can the compiler use the information that the counter is only used as a boolean to optimize out all the un-neded increments and only do a single increment.

Thanks!

Comment: probably because the first loop makes no sense and the compiler was able to figure it out by setting both to 'true' and stop looping. The second loop does some real job though and needed more code to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Serge!

With the first loop the array may have all odd, all even or no values at all and thus can't just set both values to `true`. I feel like semantically they are both doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Does it change anything to make the flags signed (such that they can’t overflow for another reason)?

Comment: Hi David, I tried making the flags int32_t and the assembly output does not seem to change.

Comment: seems like a missed optimization on the face of it, although one shouldn't assume that longer assembly translates to longer runtime